# Как сравнивать время в Python?

Tags: python, время

```
import datetime

time = datetime.time(2)


def byTime(time):
    ex = datetime.time(0)
    print(ex)
    g = datetime.time(3)
    print(g)
    if ex < time < g:
        print("excellent")
    else:
        print("ok")


print(time)
byTime(n)
```

Код выводит ошибку

> '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'int'

хотя у всех тип datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byTime(n)
```

А что у вас в `n`? Подозреваю, что там некое число. Заменяете на:

```
byTime(time)
```

И всё работает:

```
02:00:00
00:00:00
03:00:00
excellent
```

Comment: Спасибо) не заметила это